# How to run Bluetooth and Location code in background?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a need for running some code in the background. Specifically, I must listen to Bluetooth data from a connected device and listen for location changes and be able to process that data.

I am interested in how you will handle this problem?

After some investigation, I learn the following ways for running code in the background:

**1. Foreground service**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXuAzXY_KOo

Problems:

- Native code - need to transfer code for the Bluetooth handling to Native code
- iOS don't have foreground service

**2. Flutter background_fetch**

https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Problems:

- There is no way to increase the rate in which a fetch-event occurs and this plugin sets the rate to the most frequent possible — you will never receive an event faster than 15 minutes.

**3. Work manager**

https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Problems:

- Minimum frequency is 15 min. Android will automatically change your frequency to 15 min if you have configured a lower frequency.

**Update: After researching and testing we came to the next solution that covers all our needs:**

There is no exact solution for both platforms. For android, I have used always running foreground service. For iOS apparently there is no need for additional code when the application is using Bluetooth, it will not be killed by a system, or at least there are fewer chances for this. Also, my application using Bluetooth from Dart code with flutter_blue package. Maybe it is important to mention that we have continuous connection with Bluetooth devices. For never-ending Android service you can make service based on this article: https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

Comment: u might want to look at background service. https://dev.to/protium/flutter-background-services-19a4 , the gist is to create a service to poll location and bluetooth data.

Comment: @Gene correct me if I'm wrong, but this project doesn't have Bluetooth needs.

Comment: Hi mate, the link I gave you is a general direction in how you can tackle the issue. The functionalities that you want is 1) a way to prevent bluetooth from disconnecting with said device  ,2)getting data from bluetooth device , 3) a background location service which returns u lat and lng ,4) a service that runs in the background to do 1 , 2, 3 and process the info.

Comment: @Djanko hey do you get any solutions

Comment: @AsbahRiyas There is no exact solution for both platforms. For android, I have used always running foreground service. For iOS apparently there is no need for additional code when the application is using Bluetooth, it will not be killed by a system, or at least there are fewer chances for this. Also, my application using Bluetooth from Dart code. Good luck!

Comment: @Djanko With what method did you made the app always running foreground service.

Comment: @Djanko are you using Flutter blue for getting the bluetooth devices? Also can you please update the answer with your solution., im also trying to build this feature. Thanks

Comment: @AsbahRiyas We develop service based on this article https://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android

Comment: @Madvillainy Yes, we using flutter_blue, and we have continuous connection with Bluetooth device.

Answer (score 0):

To run tasks in the background, you may want to look into using [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html). Here's a sample on how Isolate can be implemented.

```dart
Isolate? isolate;

@override
void initState() {
  /// Start background task
  _asyncInit();
  super.initState();
}


_asyncInit() async {
  final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  isolate = await Isolate.spawn(_isolateEntry, receivePort.sendPort);

  receivePort.listen((dynamic data) {
    if (data is SendPort) {
      if (mounted) {
        data.send({
          /// Map data using key-value pair
          /// i.e. 'key' : String
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          /// Update data here as needed
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

static _isolateEntry(dynamic d) async {
  final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  d.send(receivePort.sendPort);

  /// config contains the key-value pair from _asyncInit()
  final config = await receivePort.first;
 
  /// send bluetooth data you received
  d.send(...);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  /// Determine when to terminate the Isolate
  if (isolate != null) {
    isolate.kill();
  }
  super.dispose();
}
```

As for bluetooth support on Flutter, you can also look into using [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue)